# Change root mount on raspberry pi from SD card to SSD

Tags: raspberrypi

Trying to transfer an existing 20.10 install to an SSD.

The Raspberry Pi 4B's firmware is updated to boot from USB. I `dd`'ed the SD card onto a SSD. Seems like it's booting off of the boot partition of the SSD now with the SSD's boot partition being mounted to `/boot/firmware`. Though comically, the SD card's second partition is still mounted as `/`.

How can I make the SSD's boot partition's configuration (presumably it's in there somewhere) point to the SSD's second partition to mount as root?

I'm assuming it's pointing to the SD card because the SSD's boot partition was cloned off of the SD card's boot partition. Editing `/etc/fstab` doesn't seem to make sense since it's a `fstab` file mounted in the SD card's root directory.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the setting is in /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt. One of the flags was `root=` and the initial setting was based on the very ambiguous ext4 label which was, I guess, by default `LABEL=writable` in the base Ubuntu 20.04 raspberry pi server image.

I set it to a more explicit UUID based on `blkid` and it works after a reboot as per `lsblk`.